# Try/Catch catches promise reject... any way around that?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, promise

I have to use try/catch because MongoDb's `ObjectId()` will break/error if arg is to short.

The  promise `.catch` never fires when the `try` is good...it seems that the outer `catch(e)` will catch the promise reject().  Is this expected behavior? anyway around that?

```
   function deleteUser(req, res) {
      try {
        var userId = { '_id': ObjectId(String(req.params.user_id)) };
        var petData = _getAllData(userId);
        petData
        .then(function(doc) {
          data.deleteAllData(doc);
          result = user.remove(userId);
          _returnApi(result, res);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log(`error delete user -${err}`);
          res.status(500).json({ error: "error deleting user" });
        });
      }
      catch(e) {
          res.status(400).json({ error: "user id format incorrect" });
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share us  _getAllData code

Comment: Try to add `exec()` after `petData.`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per those two issues [1](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3592) and [2](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3543) are discussed in Mongoose issue site, after mongoose `v4.2.5`, the *Invalid ObjectId* could be caught in `find` method through `exec()`, here are the sample codes test under mongoose `v4.4.2`

```
Foo.find({_id: 'foo'}) // invalid objectId
    .exec()
    .then(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    })
```

Output:

```
{ [CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "foo" at path "_id"]
  message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "foo" at path "_id"',
  name: 'CastError',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'foo',
  path: '_id',
  reason: undefined }
```

However, according to [this issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3512), the `update` method is still failed.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, you can reduce it to single catch block, but return different messages based on the error type then:

```
function deleteUser(req, res) {
  let userId;
  return Promise.resolve({ '_id': ObjectId(String(req.params.user_id))})
    .then(_userId => {
      userId = _userId;
      return _getAllData(userId);
    }).then(doc => {
      data.deleteAllData(doc);
      result = user.remove(userId);
      return _returnApi(result, res);
    }).catch(err => {
      if(!userId) return res.status(400).json({ error: "user id format incorrect" });
      console.log(`error delete user -${err}`);
      res.status(500).json({ error: "error deleting user" });
    });
  }
}
```